# AWS IotData sdk publish data to IoT topic using custom clientId using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-iot

I have an IoT rule which triggers a lambda function when data is published to the topic `topic/type/<clientId>/data`.

The lambda function gets data from DynamoDB and publishes the result to `topic/type/<clientId>/getData`
I also have a device connected with client id `<clientId>` whenever the lambda function is triggered my actual device disconnects, I think the lambda function is connecting with client id of my actual device (ie `<clientId>`) how do I change the client ID of my lambda function publishing data using IotData?

**index.js**

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const iot = new AWS.IotData({endpoint : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.iot.XX-XXXXXXX-X.amazonaws.com'});
exports.handler = async (event) => {

//get data from DynamoDB and other process

 var iotparams = {
            topic : "topic/"+deviceInfo.Item.deviceType+"/"+event.deviceId+"/getProfile",
            payload : JSON.stringify(profile.Item)
        };
        await iot.publish(iotparams).promise();

...

}
```

Lambda Permissions

[image]

Event JSON for test event

```json
{
  "tableName": "mytableName",
  "id": <clientId>
}
```

if I change the `<clientId>` to something other than the clientId of the IoT thing, my IoT thing doesn't restart.

I can only think of one reason for this to happen my lambda is using the same `<clientId>` but again if that the case the disconnect reason should state duplicate client id.

NOTE: Device published to `topic/type/<clientId>/data` -> IoT rule triggers lambda -> lambda get data from DynamoDB, process it and publish data to `topic/type/<clientId>/getData`

Comment: I don't think the lambda uses the same client id as your IoT Thing. Most likely the issue is elsewhere. One thing that surprises me, is the fact that you have subscribe permission for a lambda. The lambda only publishes. Then also, what is the permission of your iot thing?

Comment: @brushtakopo Every time my lambda function is invoked my IoT thing re-connects to AWS IoT. In the presence/disconnect/<clientId> I can see the disconnect reason as "CONNECTION_LOST" this only happens when my function is invoked. My IoT thing has full access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was in my device side. My buffer size was low when receiving the message so my IoT thing started to re-connect. The problem was solved by increasing the buffer size in my IoT thing code.

Comment: As I said, the problem was elsewhere :)